# Synchronise my java app with the table user of fosuserbundle

Tags: java, symfony, encryption, fosuserbundle

I am trying to create a Desktop app (using java) that points to the same database of my website (created using symfony 2),and i have a problem that I can't insert in the columns "password" and "salt" (using the same encryption type `sha512` generated by fosuserBundle),and I don't know how fosuserBundle generates the "salt" value.

My encoder is currently set as:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

Comment: The salt is generated randomly. Then each password is *salted* and *hashed*. In order to check a password, you have to perform the same steps and check that the hash in the database is the same as the generated hash from the provided password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i find a solution that makes the field "salt" negligible in the fos_user table:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder;

    protected function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt)
        {
            if (empty($salt)) {
                return $password;
            }
    
            if (false !== strrpos($salt, '{') || false !== strrpos($salt, '}')) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot use { or } in salt.');
            }
    
            return $password;
        
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` `__construct` method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    $this->enabled = false;
    $this->locked = false;
    $this->expired = false;
    $this->roles = array();
    $this->credentialsExpired = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks paul for your answer for my web site all is good but trying to insert these fields using java i dont know how to procede

Comment: What means - `I canot insert in the columns "password" and "salt" ` ?

Comment: i mean when i try to add a user using java we must define these columns using the same hashing algorithm used by fosuserBundle all of these allow to me to add user from my desktop app and connecting with the same identifiants using the website

Comment: I think that if You create new user from java app then you can set any salt as you want - you just need to encode password in this same way as `Symfony` is doing it. Then You should be able login in both places.

Comment: no it did not work even i modified  manually an existent user by delete his salt field

Comment: You can't modify existing users salt and try to match password! It will not go na work. You need to precise your question! You ask about this how salt ks generated or how user password is encoded based on that salt?  For logging users you need to apply logic from current password encoder (from Symfony) in your java app.